# Keep unique element in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I will try to explain my problem with one example.

```
df <- data.frame(VIN=paste("vin", c(1:6,2), sep = ""), 
                 KM=c(15, 48, 545, 544, 874, 6523, 1422))
```

I want to clean my `data.frame`, and keep only unique element in VIN column, in my example I duplicate "vin2", so to choose between the two I will take the VIN with the smaller KM. Here it's the second row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options to consider.

The first uses `rank`:

```
df[with(df, ave(KM, VIN, FUN = rank)) == 1, ]
#    VIN   KM
# 1 vin1   15
# 2 vin2   48
# 3 vin3  545
# 4 vin4  544
# 5 vin5  874
# 6 vin6 6523
```

The second depends on `order` and `duplicated (and seems more intuitive, in a certain manner, but will require you to sort your data before proceeding).

```
X <- df[with(df, order(VIN, KM)), ]
X[!duplicated(X$VIN), ]
#    VIN   KM
# 1 vin1   15
# 2 vin2   48
# 3 vin3  545
# 4 vin4  544
# 5 vin5  874
# 6 vin6 6523
```

Comment: thanks ! I prefer the second one. Just one more question, X[!duplicated(X$VIN), ] remove all the duplicated VIN and keeps the first one !

Comment: @MostafaRifi, I don't see a question in that comment. What's the question?

Comment: It's ok I just undersatand my problem. Thank you again !